# Not storing data and getting no output.in android

Tags: android

I have written this code for sending data to a server. It runs without reporting any errors, but when the submit button is pressed, it comes out and no data is stored.  Can you help me out?  Where is the problem?

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String name=""+etname.getText().toString();
        String age=""+etage.getText().toString();
        String email=""+etemail.getText().toString();
        List<Pair<String, String>> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new Pair<>("name", name));
        params.add(new Pair<>("age", age));
        params.add(new Pair<>("email", email));

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1/tutorials.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            in=urlConnection.getInputStream();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: where do you flush the data to the server? u just open a connection to the server.. please read this follow example for reading/writing https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a NetworkOnMainThreadException. So don't say there are no errors.

You don't have to flush.

Put your code in a thread or AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Move your onClick logic inside AsyncTask class and write that code inside doInBackground and use onPostExecute method to get result. Android do not allow network operations to perform on UI thread. Hence it is throwing NetworkOnMainThread exception.  Hope it helps .

```
public  class MyAyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,InputStream>{


@Override
protected InputStream doInBackground(String... parameters) {
    String name=""+etname.getText().toString();
    String age=""+etage.getText().toString();
    String email=""+etemail.getText().toString();
    List<Pair<String, String>> params = new ArrayList<>();
    params.add(new Pair<>("name", name));
    params.add(new Pair<>("age", age));
    params.add(new Pair<>("email", email));

    try {
        URL url = new URL(parameters[0]);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        urlConnection.connect();
        InputStream in = new        BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        in=urlConnection.getInputStream();

         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;
         }
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
    // You will get inputStream respose here . Use it to manipulate your UI.
}
```

}

In button click method

```
new MyAyncTask().execute("http://yoururl.com");
```

Error should go away.